# security risk of changing user in nginx server

Tags: server, security, nginx

I am planning to set up a server on a spare computer. I plan to use Ubuntu server 14.04 with nginx and php. I know that it is generally safe not to run a server as root user but is it ok if I set it up to run as a normal user as opposed to run it as www-data? What are the potential security risks that comes with changing the user? Keep in mind that this is a simple server that can only be accessed within the private network in home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it ok if I set it up to run as a normal user as opposed to run it as www-data?

Sure.

> What are the potential security risks that comes with changing the user?

There are no risks to changing a user. If anything changing to another user (that is NOT your admin account since you never should use that except for admin tasks on a server) will make it more secure: anyone knows there can be a user www-data when there is a website active. Now they need to guess that user name too. Setting a good password is more important.

It is not the user but the permissions set to the directories and the files that can make it risky. If you set permissions to files and directory all open for all it is riskier than when you set them as strict as possible. For someone to execute arbitrary code that person needs to be able to execute code. So set files to 644 or even 640 if possible and directories to 755 or 750 if possible and have the users that need to be allowed to edit files all in the same group.

Comment: That's not 100% true. A normal user is having a login shell configured, whereas www-data is not so there is more risc

Comment: @Rinzwind By admin account do you mean the root user? I was planning to just set it as the normal user that I log into the system with. What files and folders have to be changed? the ones in `/home/user`?

Comment: @Rumesh I would not use your login user for this - because you have sudo access likely.  Instead you should create a user as a system user - not a login user but not an admin either.

Comment: Thanks! Any chance you could link me to a good tutorial on doing so